# Acrobat X - are there command line operations to create a pdf from html

Tags: acrobat

This would be done on a Windows machine, our build script builds the documentation for our software into a framed html site.  We then want to automate the building of a pdf using the new Acrobat X.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

c:/Program Files/Adobe/Acrobat 10.0/Acrobat/acrodist /n /q /o /out-dir file.ps

where /out-dir is whatever target directory you want your file to end up in.  /n starts a new instance, and /q quits it when its done.

Here's a page that outlines all of the switches.  I haven't tested all of this with 10, but I think they work:

http://home.comcast.net/~tom.brodhead/distiller-switches.htm